# how to protect database from windows authentication

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I want to deploy .net application on client machine.I don't know how to protect my database from from windows authentication.
I want to access my database only from defined  sqlserver authenticated user.
I am Using sqlserver 2008 R2.

Comment: Open up SSMS, connect to server, go to Security > Logins and see if there are any windows logins there. Query for WinAuth logins: `SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins WHERE 1 IN (isntuser, isntgroup)`

Comment: For that you have to drop the **BUILTIN\Administraors** login. I think this is the one way for restrict the users for entering in to the server through windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc3339b8-24f4-4e5a-ae2f-fd491e93864d/how-to-disable-windows-authentication?forum=sqlsecurity):

> You cannot disable Windows Authentication on SQL Server. In fact, SQL
>   Server recognizes two modes of security: 
>         1) Windows Authentication
>         2) SQL Server AND Windows Authentication
>
> There's a way out, however. Users of the Adminstrators group of
>   Windows are able to connect to the SQL Server because there's a login
>   account in SQL Server for it and is assigned the System Administrators
>   role. You'll need to delete that login. But before you do so, please
>   be sure that 
>         1) the security mode is set to SQL Server and Windows, and
>         2) you know the password of SQL Server's sa login Otherwise, you'll render your SQL Server inaccessible!
>
> To do so, follow these steps:
>         1) Open SQL Server Enterprise Manager
>         2) Expand the nodes to reveal your SQL Server instance
>         3) Expand your SQL Server instance node to reveal the various nodes
>         4) Expand the Security node and click Logins
>         5) Right-click the BUILTIN\Administraors login and click Delete, click Yes 
>             when prompted for confirmation